Renaming column names in lists generated by a function
I am using PIconnect to pull data from a server. It iterates through a list of points and returns a list with a column name of the summary method (AVERAGE in this case).  When I run the code below, I end up with dataframe that has 300 columns all named Average. I would love to know if I can change those columns names to the point name in my script.
import pandas as pd
import PIconnect as PI
from PIconnect.PIConsts import SummaryType, TimestampCalculation

with PI.PIServer()as server:
   points = server.search('WTG*_AI_IN_TempA*')
   data = [point.summaries('5/14/2024','6/1/2024', '10m', SummaryType.AVERAGE, time_type=TimestampCalculation.EARLIEST_TIME)
   for point in points]
   data2 = pd.concat(data, axis = 1) 

When this runs here are the variables
data - List - Size 309 - Values are all Dataframes
data2 - DataFrame - Size (2448,309), All Columns are labelled AVERAGE.
I tried breaking the loop in different spots to used Pandas to rename the column, but nothing has worked.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html

How do I rename a column/list header in the loop that creates the list of lists?
